# Adding monthlySalary so I can get yearSalary?

Tags: java, methods

This is my code:

I need to make a "yearSalary" method but I can't seem to figure it out. 
To make the yearSalary method, I need the monthlySalary * 12 with 2,5% in "holiday pay".

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 2.5% in holiday pay? Is that 2.5% on top of the yearly salary or is that 2.5% taken away from the yearly salary put into something. Can you clarify the mathematical operation for the 2.5% for holiday pay?

Comment: Oh sorry, 2.5% on top of the year salary @Yashwanth

Answer (score 1):

Going off of your current functions...

```
   public int yearlySalary(){
         return getMonthlySalary() * 12 * 1.025;
   }
```

you would then call this like:

`System.out.println("Year salary: " + yearlySalary());`

Comment: I would use the getter method and have " return getMonthlySalary() * 12 * 1.025; " He has it so it is better to use it whenever you can.